# Allow RenovateBot to auto complete pull requests in Azure whilst requiring one approval

Tags: azure-devops, renovate

I'm trying to setup [RenovateBot](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate). I've configured it to automerge all pull requests it makes, but it doesn't seem able to since we also have a repository policy to require at least one approval.

renovate.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:js-app"
  ],
  "baseBranches": ["main"],
  "lockFileMaintenance": { "enabled": true },
  "automerge": true
}
```

In the pull request, it says it will auto approve:

```
Renovate configuration
 Schedule: At any time (no schedule defined).

 Automerge: Enabled.

♻️ Rebasing: Whenever PR is behind base branch, or rename PR to start with "rebase!".

 Immortal: This PR will be recreated if closed unmerged. Get config help  if that's undesired.

This PR has been generated by Renovate Bot .
```

There are no errors in the RenovateBot logs

```
INFO: Repository started (repository=<ORG>/DependencyUpdater)
       "renovateVersion": "24.78.3"
 INFO: Dependency extraction complete (repository=<ORG>/DependencyUpdater)
       "baseBranch": "main",
       "stats": {
         "managers": {"npm": {"fileCount": 1, "depCount": 1}},
         "total": {"fileCount": 1, "depCount": 1}
       }
 INFO: PR updated (repository=<ORG>/DependencyUpdater, branch=renovate/pin-dependencies)
       "pr": 5,
       "prTitle": "Pin dependency renovate to 24.78.3"
 INFO: Repository finished (repository=<ORG>/DependencyUpdater)
       "durationMs": 8798
```

Renovate is logged in as the Service User, which has the `Contribute`, `Contribute to pull requests` and `Create branch` permissions.

How can I configure Renovate/Azure DevOps to allow these pull requests to be autocompleted?

My thinking is that I need to somehow make Renovate self-approve these pull requests (although I guess that could only work because I tell ADO to require at least one approval. if it needed 2 approvals then we'd be out of luck)

Comment: Hi @berkeleybross, how are things going? Are the explanation and suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please check it. Feel free to tell us if you have any question about this.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, by default the automergeing tool will auto-merge the PR only when all the required branch policies (if any) have been met. The same is true for **Renovate**.

If you have mandatory Pull Request reviews then it means **Renovate** can't auto-merge its own PR until such a review has happened.

There are two approval helper apps ('[**renovate-approve**](https://github.com/apps/renovate-approve)' and '[**renovate-approve-2**](https://github.com/apps/renovate-approve-2)') can mark all automerging Pull Requests by **Renovate** as approved. But these two apps are only available for GitHub. For more details, you can see [here](https://docs.renovatebot.com/automerge-configuration/#required-pull-request-reviews).

There is not any available feature or extension for **Renovate** can auto-approve PR or bypass the required reviews on Azure DevOps. So, currently before the automerging, the required reviewers must manually approve the PR. Or if the approval is not must required on the PR, you can disable it from the branch policies.

Comment: Is this still up to date or is it possible by now?

Comment: @kklaw this is possible now, please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is possible as of 14/07/23.

The following config will get Renovate to automatically set the PR to complete once it has met the required policy. Note that this config does not set the [Automatic Approval](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#autoapprove) configuration property, which would lead the PR in your mentioned use case to be immediately merged.

Contents of `renovate.json` within the repository itself:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "platform": "azure",
  "automerge": true,
  "automergeType": "pr",
  "platformAutomerge": true
}
```

If you want this behaviour across all repositories, you can set this in your global renovate `config.js` using the below:

```
module.exports = {
  platform: 'azure',
  endpoint: 'https://dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORG_HERE/',
  automerge: true,
  automergeType: 'pr',
  platformAutomerge: true
}
```

Relevant links for the associated configuration:

- [platform](https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#platform)
- [automerge](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#automerge)
- [automergeType](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#automergetype)
- [platformAutomerge](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#platformautomerge)